# Dual boot with Windows 10 on Lenovo Ideapad 100

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

So I am trying to dual boot with Windows 10 and I am doing fine but here it says that my computer has no OS. And I clearly have Windows 10.

[image]

What is the problem and how to solve it?

*I know how to install, I am doing the installation well until this pops out.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You probably need to turn off Windows fast start up: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions LENOVO Ideapad 100 Laptop 16.04 Dual Boot 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336544

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when trying to dual boot Ubuntu with my lenovo ideapad 110. I have found the solution finally. I did clean swipe of my HDD on my laptop, its 1TB i partitioned it in half, after installing the win OS, i shrinked a new volume to install Ubuntu on, around 100GB dependig on available space.
I then created bootable usb using rufus, while booting, i selected the UEFI option on the menu containing the flash disk. This time round it wasnt frustrating. I can comfortably switch between the two OS. 
Tip: Use rufus to create the bootable usb, in my thinking it did create two types boot order from the flash..All the best.